# Trimming a continous std container

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, std, c++17

Assuming I have a container alike the following:

```
std::vector<int> numbers{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

What is the most efficient way to "trim" it? As in, remove elements from it but only from the beginning or end.

Lets say I want to transform 'numbers' into the container {3,4,5,6,7}. One approach I can think of to remove the '8' quite efficiently is:

```
numbers.resize(numbers.size()-2);
```

Which seems to guarantee no reallocation and the removal of all trailing elements which don't fit in the new size (in this case only the last element, 8).

Is there a similar way to do this with the beginning of the container? And, is this operation guaranteed to be O(1) as long as the arguments I pass to resize is smaller or equal than the original size of the container?

Comment: Removing elements from the beginning (or anywhere that isn't the end) of a `std::vector` requires the remaining/following elements to be copied. Also `numbers.resize(numbers.size()-2);` will remove the last 2 elements, not just the last one (though removing elements from the back does not require any copying so this isn't really better than just `erase`ing the element.). Why exactly do you need to "trim" the vector?

Comment: If you need efficient insertion/removal at the beginning or end, then give `std::deque` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One approach I can think of to remove the '8' quite efficiently is:
>
> ```
> numbers.resize(numbers.size()-2);
> ```

Assuming this was supposed to be `-1`, no, that's not what you want to do. You should always pick the tool intended for the job. In this case, if you want to just remove the last element, that's:

```
numbers.pop_back();
```

If you want to remove the last `n` elements (assuming `n <= numbers.size()` throughout), that's:

```
numbers.erase(numbers.end() - n, numbers.end());
```

This guarantees no reallocations or extra movement - it will just invoke the appropriate destructors and then shift the end pointer. If the type is trivially destructible, even the first part of this is a no-op.

If you want to remove the *first* `n` elements, that's symmetrically:

```
numbers.erase(numbers.begin(), numbers.begin() + n);
```

However, this involves shifting all of the later elements to fill in this hole - so it's a function of how many elements left over there are. `vector` is cheap to erase from the back but expensive to erase from the front (which is itself the motivation for having a `pop_back()` but not a `pop_front()`). Because of that, if you want to `trim()`, erase from the right first.

If you are doing a lot of erasing from the front, you should consider using a container that is good at trimming from both ends - like `std::deque`. The nice thing is - the code looks the same either way. You still want to use the two-iterator `erase()` to trim.

What you definitely *don't* want to do is (despite how tempting it may appear):

```
numbers.assign(numbers.begin() + 2, numbers.end() - 1);
```

That is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` does not support removing elements from the front efficiently, but `boost::circular_buffer` does: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

To a certain extent, `std::deque` supports this too, but it has some issues such as common implementations only allocating a small amount at a time, which means it is likely to allocate memory more times than `circular_buffer`.  And removing many elements from `std::deque` is not as fast, because it has to deallocate many chunks (whereas `circular_buffer` just increments an integral value).